# Graficas symfony twig

Tags: symfony3, highcharts, twig

estoy un poco nuevo en symfony quisiera graficar los datos de una DB segui esta guia https://github.com/webeweb/highcharts-bundle  pero no me funciona, alguien me podria dar una guia para realizar graficas

Gracias por su atencion

Comment: Tienes que ser más específico en tus preguntas, que error tienes? En el ReadMe de ese proyecto explica bastante bien como hacer una gráfica detalladamente.

Comment: Te recomiendo pasar los datos al front y luego construir el gráfico usando la librería js misma. puedes intentar recrear algo como https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic  pasando datos del back al front